# Fetch category wise products from mysql using php in json format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

[image]

After running this query

```
SELECT cat.id,cat.name,pro.id,pro.name,pro.price
FROM `products` as pro
JOIN categories as cat on pro.cat_id = cat.id
ORDER BY cat.id;
```

I get the result as shown in the figure. I want to fetch this using php mysql in json format something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and `JSON_OBJECT` as:

```
SELECT cat.id, cat.name, JSON_ARRAYAGG(
  JSON_OBJECT('pro_name',pro.name,'pro_pice',pro.price)
) prod
FROM products as pro
JOIN categories as cat on pro.cat_id = cat.id
GROUP BY cat.id, cat.name
ORDER BY cat.id;
```

[MySQL online query execute](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=713e596394ac01b28201b8efc6233006&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Result:

```
+====+===========+================================================================================+
| id | name      | prod                                                                           |
+====+===========+================================================================================+
| 1  | Category1 | [{"pro_name": "Prod1", "pro_pice": 10}, {"pro_name": "Prod2", "pro_pice": 12}] |
+----+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2  | Category2 | [{"pro_name": "Prod3", "pro_pice": 10}]                                        |
+----+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG does not exist I am getting this error although I using mysql 10